# Answer is three words forming a phrase (3rd of a rebus series)

Tags: rebus

[image: ...]

Find those three words which form a phrase.

**Edit:** I think there are many interpretations of the last square, so this is some more piece of information:

**Open piece of information** (so the puzzle wouldn't be too broad)

> Indefinite integral is also called **antiderivative**. The opposite of *derivative* (here, read it as something derived from something else)

Hint 1:

> Middle : the last $g$ letters of a $\ell$-letter word.

Hint 2:

> That the integral is indefinite is significant.

Hint 3:

> The answer ends in "y" but not in "gry".

Comment: Could you maybe give a hint on the KBK field? Maybe this could help to get on the right track for the other fields from context.

Comment: @A.P. The first K is on a different side with the B and the second K. The B and the second K is on the same side.

Comment: @North It's related to the rectangle on the bottom.

Comment: Both [me](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/60424/40853) and [North](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/60424/40853) have edited our existing answer with full answer suggestions. You may not get notified if an answer is edited, thus I'm posting this comment to notify you. Please take a look at them.

Comment: It's "North and I" (the first person singular pronoun is being used as a subject).

Comment: @North Hahaha... Thanks for the tip. Reminded me of [The Lego Batman Movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lego_Batman_Movie). (_"It's 'you and I' not 'I and you'"_).

Comment: anyone still trying for the last word i believe this is the list of options: http://itools.subhashbose.com/wordfind/pattern/dis%2Ay (words that start with dis and end with y). i've looked through it and can't figure it out so good luck to the rest of you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

=== New answer ===

Third line based on OP's last hint for the last box:

> assembly

Comment:

> Antiderivative of C => What is C derived from => The C programming language is influenced by the Assembly language

Giving the answer:

> Fully automated disassembly

=== Original incorrect answer ===

My guess for the **third line** (before noticing OP's added hints, which seems to invalidate this answer):

> discount

Comments:

> Based on [@Steve's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/60281/45235) for the first square, the first part is **dis** (disc / c).
>
>  Considering the C in the integral is a capital C ([as per OP](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60032/answer-is-three-words-forming-a-phrase-3rd-of-a-rebus-series#comment184182_60274)), it could be the number 100 in Roman numerals. 
>  (Feel free to correct my math here, I pieced it together with Google and Wolfram Alpha)
>  The indefinite integral of a constant is the constant times X (+ another constant, which I'll blatantly ignore for the sake of this answer), giving "100x", which can also be interpreted as a **count**.

Based on [@Matt's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/60452/45235) for the first two lines this would give the **final answer**:

> **fully automated discount**
>  (Not sure if that's a thing, but hey, it's discount!)

Comment: I like this answer.

Answer (score 10):

My guess at a full answer is;

> Fully automated disfunction

First line, per existing contributors as "Fully"

Second line;

> de is short for Deutchland. A quick search for car in German brings up Auto.

.

> kbk, following the same German train of thought, may relate to a German company that creates couplings. The image might also relate to a coupling. Couplings mate together. This makes the middle word auto + mate + d.

Third line, in part because it just seems to fit...

First part "dis" as stated by earlier contributors.

> the second box is a function, giving dis + function

Even if it is wrong, I like the phrase :-)

Comment: Two lines correct! Closest yet

Comment: Wow. Crazily ingenious.

Comment: Wait what's correct? The second or third line?

Comment: @North  Rick van Osta already tried this [third line answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/60370/30633) to thundering silence, so I think it's safe to assume it's the first two lines that are correct.

Comment: As you were so close, I won't post another answer. I believe the third word is "disintegration".

Comment: @ermanen Gareth posted that thought two days ago, also to silence. I think it’s the best answer we’ve seen so far but OP either missed it or it isn’t what they have in mind. (Or both.)

Comment: It might have to do with Google knowing the rough position of my IP adress within Germany, but when I [google for KBK](https://www.google.de/search?q=kbk) I get lots of results other than [KBK Antriebstechnik](http://www.kbk-antriebstechnik.de/). For me the top result is a [fashion seller](https://www.kbk.de/).

Comment: @ermanen Incorrect word

Comment: You can use the third hint to search in the [english dictionary](https://visca.com/regexdict/) for the RegExp string `^dis\w*y$`. Maybe with that one can figure out the third line.

Comment: Bounty awarded for most progress made.

Answer (score 9):

**Partial answer:**

The first word is

> Molly

because

> we take the first two letters from **mo**ney, the given **l** and the two-letter abbreviation for **l**ight**y**ear. Lightyear, because lightspeed is usually denoted as $c$. And $c$ times $365$ days is the length that light travels in a year.

---

**Ideas about the last line:**
As already pointed out by others

> the first three letters are **dis**.

Furthermore, we have the OP's third hint that

> the word ends in **y**, but not in **gry**.

So I did

> a [search through the english dictionary](https://visca.com/regexdict/) for the [RegExp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) `^dis\w*y$` and found 35 results. Unfortunately none of them rung a bell.

Not being a native speaker this is not surprising, but I'd like to share some ideas that weren't mentioned yet. The $\int C$ could be

> read as
>
> - "integral sea [salt]"
>
>   "integral sea[t]" (and then substract the t from the final word)
>
> and then associated with one of the words from the dictionary.

Comment: First line almost correct.

Comment: @user_194421 Can please specify that? Is he close because of the first square or the third?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Second and third square correct.

Comment: is it perhaps, dolly?

Comment: @Dest [Nope](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/60324/5373).

Comment: How did you get salt from?

Comment: @North There is no salt involved, it should be some kind of citation with omission. Maybe that gets somebody further.

Answer (score 9):

**partial answer**
Third line
updated answer

> **first square**
>  Disc/C = Dis
> **second square**
>  Integrate or integration
>  together gives: Disintegrate or Disintegration

original answer - disproved by OP comment

> **first square**
>  CD/C = D
> **second square**
>  integral of light speed = light distance = light-d
> D-light-d = delighted

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling :) That's a really good try, probably what OP intended.

Comment: Incorrect, first square not too far, but second quite far away

Comment: What's the etiquette for revising answers in puzzling given comments on the answer? I have another idea given OP's comment

Comment: @Steve - please feel free to refine your answers as needed, most answers to tricky puzzles go through several iterations, based on input from the OP, from others, and by deriving off others' answers.

Comment: @Steve - if you're changing your answer significantly, you are entitled to either replace it with a new one, or put the revised answer on top and keep the old one as a "Previously, my line of thought was this..." type of footer - this is personal preference in case you wish to show how you went through the solving process.

Comment: Updated, if this isn't it then I'm stumped

Comment: @Steve First square correct, second square still incorrect.

Answer (score 6):

After reading the comments under @North answer (along with the answer of course), I think the first line is:

> **Fully**.

Because:

> The money in the first square is a ***fund***, and the rest is explained in the other answers.

---

#### Edit:

Full answer:

> **Fully automated display.**

Because:

> The first word is *"fully"*. (credit goes to [@A.P.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/60252/40853)for *"lly"* and to [@North](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/60424/revisions) for *"u"*).
>
>  The second word is *"automated"*. (full credit goes to [@Matt Stevens](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/60452/40853)).
>
>  The third word is *"display"*: The indefinite integral is an [antiderivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative). Antiderivatives are known to have a [constant of integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_integration) C that you can ***play*** with the numbers to change its value and get the antideriviative you want (the weakest explanation ever). Also a google search didn't yield much words that match *"full automated dis*y"*. (credit goes to [@Steve](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/60281/40853) for *"dis"*).

Comment: Two lines to go...

Comment: Well done!!! Nice job... TEAMWORK +1 @ibrahim mahrir

Comment: @North Yeah. I got to say, though, you're terrible at finishing rebus. You come so close and then get stuck (speaking about my question too).

Comment: So true, so true....

Comment: Hmm, nice answer. Wouldn't have thought of that

Comment: Though there are actually quite a bit of words that start with dis and end with y http://www.fatlingo.com/wordguru/starts-with-and-ends-in/dis+y

Comment: @North actually I was refering to the whole pack all together (fully followed by automated followed by the **"list of words that start with dis and end with y"**).

Comment: Oh, I see. However, perhaps the OP picked three random words and put them together, so you can't just go to Google and look it up.

Comment: Incorrect. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 5):

**Partial answer of the third line:**

First square:

> We have a CD.
>  lightspeed = c
>  $\frac{cd}{c} = d$

Second square:

> $\int{c}$

> $c$ is a the lightspeed, which is a velocity. Velocity is lenght or distance divided by time. Velocity is also the derivative of distance over time.
>  Since velocity is a derivative, by integrating it (assuming it should be "$\int{c\;dt}$"), we get a constant length or distance.

Which distance exactly?

> Depends on time. Getting a hint from the first line, which also references $c$ and references a year, so it could be a lightyear.

Joining the parts:

> $d\;ly$ would be the derivative of a lightyear distance. However the derivative of distance is again velocity, and this bring us back to $c$.

Comment: The $C$ in the last box is a capital $C$ (at least it looks like that to me). So it could stand for capacitance or any constant.

Comment: @A.P. That is correct, it's a capital C.

Comment: The answer is not very close

Comment: @AhmedAshour The $\int{c}$ is already part of the question, so there is no need to hide it.

Comment: If the "C" is a constant and the integrel function is indefinite, doesnt that make it redundant? Because an integral function has an arbitrary constant, if C is a constant, then thats just repeating itself. Of course, I don't take calculus and idnt even know hwta the integral sign was until yesterday, so I could be wrong

Answer (score 3):

Is the final answer

> FULLY AUTOMATED DISSOLUTION?

First line solved by [ibrahim mahrir](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/60425/5373) inspired by [A.P.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/60252/5373).

Second line solved by [Matt Stevens](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/60452/5373).

Third line:

> first part DIS solved by [Steve](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/60281/5373), second part SOLUTION because the indefinite integral of a constant $c$ is a linear function $cx+d$, where $x$ is the variable of integration.

Could be a stretch, but this seemed to be the best fit from among these possibilities:

> [image: Google autocomplete for "fully automated dis..."]

Comment: I swear I was going to post the same answer but had no idea how to justify it. I would've never thought of using a screenshot of Google search. Nice one.

Comment: BTW my answer was inspired by [@North's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/60424/revisions) not A.P's.

Comment: @Ibrahim I saw that, but A.P. was the first person to successfully find LLY, so you were *ultimately* inspired by A.P. via North :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Still incorrect. I have posted the third hint.

Answer (score 2):

**First line**

[A.P.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/60252/5373) is almost correct, but in fact it's

> DOLLY: from the first two letters of **DO**LLAR, then an **L**, then the initials of **L**ight **Y**ear ($c$ is light speed, then 365d is a year).

**Second line**

No idea yet.

> The first square could be something like DECAR? But I don't even know what the image in the second square is meant to be.

**Third line**

Could it be

> DISCO or DISCS? The first square gives **DIS**C without $c$ (lightspeed), as [Steve](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/60281/5373) said, and the second square is $\int c$, which (if $c$ is a constant) will be $c$ times the variable of integration.

Comment: Every line.. incorrect answer, the first line is still incorrect.

Comment: Well damn `:-(`

Comment: Nice try. No idea what KBK right-side-green means. Also, I think that the fact that it is an ancient car instead or a regular present-day car to be relevant.

Comment: @Victor Well hello! :-D Maybe the old car is a *jalopy* or something? If only we knew what KBK could stand for. (Your answer is good too, btw; already upvoted.)

Comment: de-horseless carriage seems unlikely to be the right direction :-).

Comment: First line also works if you use $\color{white}{\text{dough}}$. :-P

Comment: It might be "$\color{white}{\text{CALLY}}$".

Comment: @user_194421 More thoughts: first line could be rot13{gbgnyyl} (because the 2 sounds like "to"); second line could be rot13{qrgrezvarq} (though I'm a bit doubtful about this). Any joy?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Not even close

Comment: @user_194421 Well damn `:-(`

Answer (score 2):

**Partial answer**

Most elements of this have been given by others already; think of this as summing up the current state of the art.

First line/word:

> [something] + L + LY; we don't know whether the "2" means "first two letters" or "two different money-related words" or "word denoting two units of some kind of money" or what. We know (because OP has told us) that it isn't MOLLY or DOLLY.

Second line/word:

> I suspect the car in the first box is a Ford Model T, and this word begins DET. Or it could begin DECAR, but if I understand OP's comment on Rand's answer right then it doesn't. Presumably the D at the end is literal. The middle box is a big mystery.

Third line/word:

> First box is almost certainly DIS. (I think OP's comment on Steve's answer confirms this.) Second box is a mystery.

So we seem to have

> ~~~LLY DET~~~D DIS~~~.

Some comments on the start of the first line:

> If -LLY is correct, then most likely the first box yields something ending in A. On the face of it, the most likely meaning of that "2" is that we are to take two things-indicating-money; but, while there are e.g. some currencies whose names end in A, none of them seems to give anything useful. (e.g., "...PESETALLY"? Nope.) CENTRALLY is tempting (beginning with CENT) but I don't see any way to justify the RA, nor have I thought of any plausible phrases beginning CENTRALLY DET... .

Some comments on the middle of the second line:

> Perhaps the image means that KBK indicates (by being the initials? in some other way?) a name, long word, phrase, etc., that decomposes into a long bit + a short bit + a long bit, and we need the second long bit. [EDITED to add: OP has now posted a hint that confirms my interpretation of the image and indicates that it's a word rather than a phrase.] But so far I've failed to find anything plausible that KBK might mean. And it doesn't seem plausible that what this box yields begins with K ("DETK..."?!!), which you might expect if this is how it works. Most plausible words of the form DET~~~D: detoxed, detuned, detached, detailed, detained, detected, deterred, detested, detoured, dethroned, detonated, detracted, determined, detoxified, deteriorated. None of them very plausible, either in terms of fitting the rebus or in terms of making a familiar-sounding phrase.

Some comments on the end of the third line:

> Someone suggested things like DISINTEGRATION for the line as a whole, but I think the "C" in this box has to be significant. If we take it to be a constant then we can get "CT" or "CX" or something, but I don't see that that works. What else is conventionally designated C? Capacitance. (Not a thing that often needs integrating.) Circumference, maybe. (Integral would be the area of some sort of surface made out of circles, like a disc or a sphere. DISA and DISAREA are not words.) All sorts of other even-less-integrable things. It's fairly common to denote the arbitrary constant you get from doing an integral by C, but why you'd be integrating *that* I'm not sure, and anyway DISCONSTANT is no good and making DISC by starting with DISC, deleting C, and then adding C seems rather unsatisfactory.

Comment: Incorrect answer

Comment: I don't really know what that means. I didn't give an answer to the whole thing. I suggested lots of partial answers to individual bits. Oh well, never mind.

Comment: None of the words you mentioned is a word in the answer.

Comment: That would seem a reasonable definition of "incorrect" :-).

Answer (score 2):

#### Original:

Partial answer:

> I think the first line is cally. Take the first two letters of cash, add it to lly, and you get cully. Btw, cally is a sland word for the police

Rejected by OP.

---

#### Edit #1:

Another partial answer:

> For the second box on the last row, what if C is 100 (since In Roman numerals, C is 100)
>  Or maybe its 300,000 since light speed travels approximately at that speed.

Rejected by OP.

---

#### Edit #2:

Final answer:

> **Fully Automated Discontinuity.**

Because:

> *"Fully"*, *"automated"* and *"dis"* are already explained by the other contributors.
>  *"Continuity"*: correct me if I'm wrong, but an indefinite integral is infinite, or continuous. Also, it starts with a *"C"*, which is what perhaps that *"C"* in the integral thingy is.

Comment: I too think this is the correct answer (there aren't much words that match OP's criteria and this seem to fit). Already upvoted yesterday.

Comment: Incorrect. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

Since good answers haven't gotten us elsewhere, time to try maybe not-so-good answers. So ...

> **Fully automated discovery**

as in

> A ["protocol which allows fully automated discovery of elementary chemical reaction steps"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.01041), or an algorithm with ["application to the fully automated discovery of patterns in 974 PROSITE families"](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11108480), or these researchers' goal ["to develop a well-founded methodology to support an efficient and fully-automated discovery and composition of Web services."](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fb66/b4e666a96bd668f975035d6b19aebe87aa7a.pdf)

The first two words have been discovered and confirmed already;

> **Fully** in [@ibrahim mahrir's answer](/a/60425) (inspired by [@A.P.](/a/60252)), and
>  **automated** found in [@Matt Stevens' answer](/a/60452).

The final word, from [@Steve's answer](/a/60281) and OP's third hint, we know

> starts with **dis** and ends with **y**.
>  The second box for this word is $\int{C}$.
>  Integrated with respect to $y$, this should be ${\rm C}y + \rm A$.
>  That doesn't really get us anywhere.

However, if instead we go through some admittedly tortured gyrations ...

> • Integration is the inverse of differentiation.
>  • Differentiation is indicated by $\frac{dy}{dx}$.
>  • The inverse of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is $\frac{dx}{dy}$.
>  • With $x$ now representing the function, this equals $\frac{d}{dy}~\rm C$.
>  • Pretending now that $d$ is just a variable, this equals $\require{cancel}\frac{\cancel{d}}{\cancel{d}y}~\rm C = \Large\frac{C}{y}$.
>  • This can be read as "C over y".

If that's the solution to the second box, that gives us

> **dis** + **C over y** $\implies$ **discovery** which, per the hint, ends in y.

Comment: Incorrect. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Answer**

First Line

> Taking the first two letters of the word "CASH" gives CA, then adding the L from the second square and the C from the third square indicates that it probably should be a word beginning in 'Calc', like 'Calculate' or 'Calcium'. Not sure what to do with the 365d though (could be a year?)..

Second Line

> Maybe something like "Decarbonated", not sure about the second square though.

Third Line

> Disfunction?

Comment: Incorrect answer

Answer (score 1):

Most of the hard work is already done but my guess is

> Fully Automated Disciplinary

To explain the last bit

> Plenary is synonymous with unlimited which is another way of describing an indefinite integral. So the last square could be interpreted as a "C-plenary" and thus 
> "dis" + "C-plenary" = Disciplinary. 
>  It also gets some hits on google.

The rest of the puzzle has already been explained in other answers.

Comment: Incorrect. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be...

> Fully 
>  Automated 
>  Luminosity

The first two words had already been answered.

For the 3rd word originally I had thought it to be

> Luxury

because the disc image could also mean cd, or candela. But with the latter image equating to function and using the hint that the the word ends in y. I have derived that the 3rd word of the phase is

> Luminosity

Because it applies to a function. And because, A related quantity is integrated

> luminosity

which is the integral of the

> luminosity

with respect to time.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Could you explain your answer, please? Answers without any explanation are likely to get deleted.

Comment: Incorrect answer.